# A question about data management

Tags: probability

> Of the students at a high school who take both mathematics and English, $83\%$ pass English, $65\%$ pass both mathematics and English, and $5\%$ fail both subjects. What is the probability of passing mathematics and failing English for this group of students?

I have thought about this for a long time and am completely clueless.

I've tried $0.17 \times 0.5$ which is the chance of failing English times the chance of failing both classes and got the answer $0.085$ which is $8.5\%$. I don't think I'm doing it right....

Comment: Please do share the thoughts you had over a long time. It would make it easier for people to help.

Comment: I've tried 0.17 X 0.5 which is the chance of failing english times the chance of failing both classes and got the answer 0.085 which is 8.5 %. I don;t think im doing it right....

Comment: If I were you, I would add those thoughts to your question. People would probably be more inclined to help and your question would be more favorably received.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a table of the information you're given:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
{} & \genfrac{}{}{0}{0}{\textsf{failed English}}{\strut} & \genfrac{}{}{0}{0}{\textsf{passed English}}{(\textsf{total of this column: }83\%\textsf{)}}\\\hline
\textsf{failed math} & 5\% & \\\hline
\textsf{passed math} & & 65\% \\\hline
\end{array}$$
I'll edit this table by

- removing an unnecessary piece of information
- pointing out a piece of information you should be interested in

and I'll remind you that **everyone** either passes or fails a given class.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
{} & \genfrac{}{}{0}{0}{\textsf{failed English}}{(\textsf{total of this column: }???\textsf{)}} & \genfrac{}{}{0}{0}{\textsf{passed English}}{(\textsf{total of this column: }83\%\textsf{)}}\\\hline
\textsf{failed math} & 5\% & \\\hline
\textsf{passed math} & & \\\hline
\end{array}$$

Can you figure out what to do?

Comment: Sorry, im still a little bit confused. I'm not sure what to do with the 65 % that passed both. It would mean that 30 % don't pass one of the two subjects?

Comment: I tried to help by telling you that $65\%$ is an irrelevant number (for this specific question at any rate). The thought that I tried to lead you to is: **if $83\%$ of people pass English, what percentage of people** ***fail*** **English?**

Comment: Oh right, sorry about that. 17 % of people fail english, 5 % fail both classes which means 12 % fail english alone? The part that confuses me is how do i answer the question which is what is the probability of Passing math and failing english.

Comment: The statement *"$12\%$ of people fail English alone"* means the exact same thing as *"$12\%$ of people fail English and pass math"*, so you have your answer right there.

Comment: Glad to help - if my answer is satisfactory, you should be able to click the checkmark on the upper left to "accept" my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a basic formula for such problems that you must be knowing:

**$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$**

Let A = pass English, B = pass Math mathematics

Since 5% fail, 95% pass, so **$P(A\cup B) = 0.95, P(A) = 0.83,P(A\cap B) = 0.65$**

Thus 0.95 = 0.83 + P(B) - 0.65, which yields P(B) = 0.77

Finally, P(Pass pass mathematics but fail English) = P(pass *only* mathematics)

= 0.77 - 0.65 = 0.12